# CSS3 Alternating table rows opacity affects text as well as background

Tags: html, css

I am trying to come up with some CSS to match a style I have in my iPhone/Android apps.  I have alternating row colors with opacity so my custom page background bleeds through.  However, the issue I am having is that I don't want the text in the table cells to also be opaque.  I want the text to have a opacity of 1.0 and the background to be an opacity = 0.12.  See [here](http://imagebin.org/185151) for what it looks like now.

CSS below:

```
html {
   -webkit-background-size: cover;
   -moz-background-size: cover;
   -o-background-size: cover;
   background-size: cover;
   height: 100%;
   background-image: url(../images/mmbg@2x.png);
}
table {
   background-color: transparent;
   margin-left: 0px;
   margin-right: 0px;
   margin-top: 10;
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   border: 0;
   border-collapse: collapse;
}
tr {
   text-align: center;
   padding: 0;
}
td {
   font-family: verdana;
   color: #ffffff;
   text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #77777777, 2px 2px 7px #ff0000;
   padding: 0;
}
tr:nth-child(odd)    { background-color:#003366; opacity:.12; filter:alpha(12); }
tr:nth-child(even)      { background-color:#6a737d; opacity:.12; filter:alpha(12); }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `rgba` colors as background. `opacity` will affect child elements and there's not much to do about it.

Answer (score 0):

Use rbga background colour (CSS3) and set the opacity in that.
    background-colour = rgba(255,255,255,0.12);

Using normal opacity affects the children of the element, so the text just gets 100% of the parents opacity, which in this case is 0.12

Comment: Correct but mis-leading to readers. It's not that its inherited (as inheritence can be overriden). Its the fact that your making something transparent and therefore anything within that will be of that transparency. If you make the parent 50% transparent, the children are still 100% visible. If you then make the children 50% transparent you making the children 75% transparent (50% of 50%). in relation to the main documents transparency

Comment: Thanks for that - have modified wording to try and make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to put the child elements in front of the parent element to make them un-affected from the parent's opacity.

for the parent: `z-index:10`
for the children:`z-index:11`